# Show that $|x-1|+|x-2|+\cdots+|x-100|\geq 50^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: inequality

I see the relation with $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i\,|\geq\left|\sum_{i=1}^na_i\,\right|$. 
But in the right hand side we get
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{100}(x-i)\,\right|=|100x-50\cdot101|=50|2x-101|$$ 
And I don't know what step should I do next.
How am I supposed to rearrange this sum to get the proof ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: note that $|x-k|+|x-(100-k+1) \ge |x-k-x+100-k+1| = 101 - 2k\,$, then sum for $k=1,2,\dots,50\,$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$|x-\ell|+|x-50-\ell| \ge |x-\ell - (x-50-\ell)| = 50$$

Comment: That's the more direct approach in this case (+1).

Answer (score 3):

Observe that, for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
|\alpha| + |\alpha + n| =
\begin{cases}
2\alpha + n , & \text{if}\ \alpha\geq 0,\\
n, & \text{if}\ -n\leq \alpha\leq 0,\\
-2\alpha-n, & \text{if}\ \alpha \leq -n,
\end{cases}
$$
so that
$$
|\alpha| + |\alpha + n| \geq n
\qquad\forall\alpha\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Hence you get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2n} |x-k| =
\sum_{k=1}^n (|x-k| + |x-k + n|)
\geq \sum_{k=1}^n n = n^2,
$$
and your inequality follows choosing $n=50$.

Comment: `|α|+|α+n|≥n` Just as an observation, this follows directly from the triangle inequality $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$ for $a = \alpha$ and $b = -\alpha-n\,$.

Comment: Yes, sure. It's enough to write $n = |n+\alpha-\alpha| \leq |n+\alpha| + |\alpha|$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x<1$, then $5050-100x\ge 50^2 \Rightarrow x\le 25.5$

If $x>100$, then $100x-5050\ge 50^2 \Rightarrow x\ge 75.5$

Assume:
$$n<x<n+1, n\in [1,100]$$
Then:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{100} |x-k|=nx-\frac{(1+n)n}{2}+\frac{(n+1+100)(100-n)}{2}-(100-n)x=$$
$$(2n-100)x-n^2-n+5050\ge 50^2 \Rightarrow$$
$$(n-50)(2x-n-51)\ge 0.$$
which is true for all $x$ such that $n<x<n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

As $t\mapsto |t|$ is convex, by Jensen’s inequality
$$|x-1|+|x-2|+...+|x-50|+|51-x|+|52-x|+...|100-x| \geqslant 100\times \left| \frac{(x-1)+(51-x) +...(x-50)+(100-x)]}{100}\right|=50^2$$